# How to display new lines where comma is there in address field in pdf generation using laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, html2pdf

I am trying to display address in new lines  where comma is there like my adress as

```
#23, "Hari Prem Building", 1st Floor, Off CMH Road, Indiranagar, Bangalore, India
```

I just want to display my address as like

```
#23,
"Hari Prem Building",
1st Floor,
Off CMH Road,
Indiranagar,
Bangalore,India
```

For this i was trying the laravel syntax like `{!! nl2br(e($inv->Address)) !!}` but its not working for me ?
Please help me out to solve this issue..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how pdf reads a newline, so you'll have to adjust it accordingly, but a simple way to do this would be:

```
$string = '#23, "Hari Prem Building", 1st Floor, Off CMH Road, Indiranagar, Bangalore, India';

$array = explode(',',$string);
echo implode(',' . PHP_EOL ,$array);
```

Then you'd simply need to replace `PHP_EOL`with the appropriate line break. Like so:

```
echo implode(', \n' ,$array); //with \n
echo implode(', <br />' ,$array); //With <br />
```